# JSON, ASP.NET MVC - MaxJsonLength exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I am just trying to shift some comma separated numbers to the frontend:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult GetSquares()
{
 var result = new JsonResult();
 result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
IList<double> list = new List<double>();
...
result.Data = list;
return result;
}
```

This works fine as long as there are only a few numbers. Unfortunately, I have to shift lots of numbers occasionally and get a MaxJsonLength exception. I tried several suggestions to overcome this (add something to the web.config file etc.). Maybe I do not have to use JSON after all? However I still 'have to do something' with the numbers using javascript. I am using jquery's ajax stuff at the moment.

Any suggestions welcome ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work?

```
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

If not maybe you can just pass it back as a string...

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult GetSquares()
{
    IList<double> list = new List<double>();
    ....
    return Content(string.Join(",", list));
}
```

Comment: try just passing back the string, json might be overkill for what you're doing. If you had a structured object I would say use json but if it's just a comma delimited string then this should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

[Here is another custom `JsonResult` (*`CorrectJsonResult`*)](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/03/23/submitting-my-first-bug-after-asp-net-mvc-1-0-rtm-release.aspx) which handles larger serialization limits that the default 4MB allowed by `JavascriptConverter`.

[And another example which uses `ContentResult`](http://dukelupus.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/asp-net-mvc-json-string-too-long-a-solution/) instead of `JsonResult` subclass.

```
public ActionResult GetLargeJsonResult()
{
  return new ContentResult
  {
    Content = new JavaScriptSerializer { MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue }.Serialize(myBigdata),
    ContentType = "application/json"
  };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have extended the base class Controller and work great:

**ControllerExtensions class:**

```
namespace SCAWEB.Helpers
{
    public static class ControllerExtensions
    {
        #region Json
        public static int MaxJsonLength{get;set;}

        static ControllerExtensions()
        {
            MaxJsonLength = 2147483644;
        }

        public static System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult LargeJson(this System.Web.Mvc.Controller controlador, object data)
        {
            return new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult()
            {
                Data = data,
                MaxJsonLength = MaxJsonLength,
            };
        }
        public static System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult LargeJson(this System.Web.Mvc.Controller controlador, object data, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
        {
            return new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult()
            {
                Data = data,
                JsonRequestBehavior = behavior,
                MaxJsonLength = MaxJsonLength
            };
        }
        //TODO: You can add more overloads, the controller class has 6 overloads
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**MyController class:**

```
using SCAWEB.Helpers;

namespace SCAWEB.Controllers
{
    public class VentasController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult VentasList (){
            //Todo: All the action code

            //return this.Json(myData);
            return this.LargeJson(myData);//Here I use my extensions
        }
    }
}
```

**You can especify the max length in your code:**

```
ControllerExtensions.MaxJsonLength = 1073741824;//1GB
```

Answer (score 3):

See explaination and LargeJsonResult class at 
http://brianreiter.org/2011/01/03/custom-jsonresult-class-for-asp-net-mvc-to-avoid-maxjsonlength-exceeded-exception/