# JavaScriptSerializer seems to ignore the maxJsonLength configuration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc, javascriptserializer

I was facing the max json length problem so as suggested by various sources on the internet, i increased the default json length in the configuration file like

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="900000000"></jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

but the problem persisted. Then i came across a fantastic [**blog post**](http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/large-json-result-for-teleriks-mvc-grid/) that suggested to write my own ActionResult. i am using the telerik grid for mvc along with mvc3.net. Any idea why the serializer ignoring the config.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MaxJsonLength exception in ASP.NET MVC during JavaScriptSerializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692836/maxjsonlength-exception-in-asp-net-mvc-during-javascriptserializer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having struggled with this myself, unfortunately, for now, this is the only solution.

Also see this question and answer for more details: [MaxJsonLength exception in ASP.NET MVC during JavaScriptSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692836/maxjsonlength-exception-in-asp-net-mvc-during-javascriptserializer)

Answer (score 1):

**MaxJsonLength and ASP.NET MVC**

In ASP.NET MVC, it seems you need to set the MaxJsonLength during the execution:

```
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    var model = GetModel();

    var outputJsonResult = Json(model);
    outputJsonResult.MaxJsonLength = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB

    return outputJsonResult;
}
```