# Error The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property

Tags: json, kendo-grid

I am currently have a grid with PDF attachment. Each PDF can have file size up to 1MB. The problem is I am getting the value "*Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property*"

I already placed the following in the web.config but the problem is it works only if the Kendo UI Grid needs to display 6 records.

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength = "2147483647"></jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in web.config?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Based on the following link:

[MaxJsonLength exception in ASP.NET MVC during JavaScriptSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692836/maxjsonlength-exception-in-asp-net-mvc-during-javascriptserializer)

```
public ActionResult SomeControllerAction()
{
  var jsonResult = Json(veryLargeCollection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
  return jsonResult;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice that they set this up in config file so not to have to add the extra code here. Thanks!

Comment: Hello ! Here I'm getting error of exceeded max length when I post request with above 600 length of array list in json. I'm passing all data to controller.