# The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property when returing PartialView

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I am receiving this error and I know what the reason is. I found multiple discussions of this problem: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848289/error-the-length-of-the-string-exceeds-the-value-set-on-the-maxjsonlength-proper), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692836/maxjsonlength-exception-in-asp-net-mvc-during-javascriptserializer), and [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1356198.aspx?Changing%20maxJsonLength%20property%20in%20web%20config%20has%20no%20effect) for example

They would work for me but my action retruns a partial view instead of Json result:

```
public ActionResult GetData(string key)
{
 var model = dB.GetSata(key);
 return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/InfoPartial.cshtml",model);
}

@model MyWeb.Models.InfoModel

@if (Model != null)
{
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyWeb.Models.InfoModel>().Name("Info").BindTo(Model))
    //... more code here
}
```

How do I incorporate my custom js serializer with extended length:

```
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

                var result = new ContentResult
                {
                    Content = serializer.Serialize(sites),
                    ContentType = "application/json",
                };
```

into my Action code when I need to return a PartialView ?

PS: this does not work

```
<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength = "2147483647"></jsonSerialization>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem using Kendo UI Grid and ended up replacing the default JsonValueProviderFactory as mentioned in this post

[JsonValueProviderFactory throws "request too large"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509721/jsonvalueproviderfactory-throws-request-too-large?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: While this might be a valid answer, you will want to provide the relevant code and an explanation of what makes this answer correct.