# Web API - The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to return a large set o json (about 2MB) but the web api returns the error:

"*Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property*". I've tried configure the maxJsonLength property in the web.config but without success.

I've seen another [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848289/error-the-length-of-the-string-exceeds-the-value-set-on-the-maxjsonlength-proper) in the stackoverflow but all related to a regular .NET MVC Controller and not an ApiController.

It's possible to bypass the internal JavaScriptSerializer maxJsonLenght or by doing some custom JsonSerializerType format?

Comment: Hi @Coastpear what version of webapi are you using? depending on which version you are using the override will change a little.

Comment: I'm using version 5.1.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Depending on just how large the JSON payload becomes, you may have to stream the response. See [this blog post](http://dblv.github.io/2014/07/02/streaming-web-api/). In short that blog post can be summarised by the below code:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage PushStreamContent()
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse();

    response.Content = 
    new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
    {
        foreach (var staffMember in _staffMembers)
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, staffMember);
                stream.Flush();
            }
        }
    });

    return response;
}
```

Comment: It didn't resolve my problem but lead me to a possible resolution, using StringContent instead I can flush the content to the browser the only problem is that it not comes with the content type "applicataion/json" but with "text/plaintext"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the [MaxJsonDeserializerMembers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) in web.config?

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="1000" />
    </appSettings>
```

Comment: Yes, it didn't work because that config it's for asp.net runtime and not for internal javascriptSerializer usage. This "internal javascriptSerializer" doesn't look for any config in the web.config. But thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @BMac for your help, you lead me to a solution that works.

```
[HttpGet]
//ResponseType it's for ApiDescription successfully generates the helper page with the right type since i'm returning a plain/text content
[ResponseType(typeof(YourType))]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetLargeJsonDataWithWebAPI()
{
    String url = "someUrl";
    String jsonData = EnvironmentUrlHelper.GetJsonResourseAsync<YourType>(url);


    var response = Request.CreateResponse();
    response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rsp));

    return response;
}
```