# Web.config jsonSerialization maxJsonLength ignored

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webclient, javascriptserializer

I have an `MVC3` application running under `.NET 4.0` and when I use `JavascriptSerializer.Deserialize` I'm getting an error.

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

Reading [Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config) I put the `jsonSerialization maxJsonLength` key in my web.config but it gets ignored. Though I can set the `JavaScriptSerializer.MaxJsonLength` property in code and it works fine.

I would like to have the value in the `Web.config` rather than code. Here is how I am using `JavaScriptSerializer`.

```
Dim client As New WebClient
...
Dim result = _client.DownloadString("Test")
Dim serializer = New JavaScriptSerializer
Return serializer.Deserialize(Of Foo)(result)
```

Here is my `Web.config`

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    ...
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
    ...
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Http404"/>
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="/Http403"/>
      <error statusCode="550" redirect="/Http550"/>
    </customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
 <system.webServer>
 ....
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the link you provided (the 2nd most voted answer), your web.config setting will be ignored because you're using an **internal instance** of the `JavaScriptSerializer`.

If you need the value to be stored in the web.config, you could add a key in the `<appSettings>` section called `maxJsonLength` with a value of `50000000` and then in your code, you could use it like:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.MaxJsonLength = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings['maxJsonLength'];
```

Comment: You should bold **internal instance**. That's what i misread!

Comment: Done. Also just realized I gave you a C# example, didn't see your vb.net tag until now :)