# MaxJsonLength Error For Large Data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3 and I am trying to return a data set and display the results using jQuery (Easy Query).

This works for smaller data sets however with a large data set it is showing the error as : `Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.`

I have tried to set `maxJsonLength` in `web.config` but the change has no effect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692836/maxjsonlength-exception-in-asp-net-mvc-during-javascriptserializer

Comment: Where I need to add this?Can you explain

Comment: Looking at the answer, it would appear that it needs to be added before you return a JSON result from the controller action.  Voting to close as this is a duplicate issue From the question @Mate referenced.