# EasyUI Datagrid rows could not be posted to the corresponding action in ASP.NET MVC4 when the rows count more than 125

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I met a issue which is the Ajax could not post a more than 125 rows of data to the corresponding action in the ASP.NET MVC4.
When the row count is less than 125, everything could be OK.
So it's strange here.

[JS Ajax]

```
$("#btnExport").click(function () {
    var rows = $("#List").datagrid("getRows"); 

    $.ajax({
        url: "/SysException/Export?sysExceptionModels",
        data: JSON.stringify(rows), 
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
        if (data.type == 1) {
            $("#aExportExcel")[0].click(); 
            $.messageBox5s('提示', data.message);
            } else {
            $.messageBox5s('提示', data.message);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[ASP.NET MVC4]

```
    static List<SysExceptionModel> _sysExceptionModelModels = null;

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Export(List<SysExceptionModel> sysExceptionModels)
    {
        _sysExceptionModelModels = sysExceptionModels;
        if (_sysExceptionModelModels == null)
        {
            return Json(JsonHandler.CreateMessage(0, "no data，could not export！"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(JsonHandler.CreateMessage(1, "export sucessfully！"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

one row is like below:

```
0000688A-85F5-4F72-BE86-85BCADED2DE NULL BBBB BBBB BBBB BBBB BBBB 2015-10-22 02:27:38.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are exceeding the max serialization size.
Try increasing the MaxJsonDeserializerMembers value in your web.config. 
Default value is 1000, which might be a bit too small.
150000 might be a better value:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: It works,appreciate.BTW,for the class JavaScriptSerializer,when i use its method named 'Serialize', I also met the exceeding the max serialization size issue.Should I add the extensions like below?<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>

Comment: A different topic; I think this post answers your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692836/maxjsonlength-exception-in-asp-net-mvc-during-javascriptserializer