# Convert MVC bytearray to dowloadable javascript file

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I managed to obtain from Microsoft MVC the bytearray of a file, its name and mimetype. I get that data from an Ajax call made with jQuery and get in console the following data:

```
data: {
  stream: [68, 82, 0, 0, 4, 57, 0, 0, 7, 179, 8, 6, 0, 0,…],
  filename: "testFile.png",
  mime: "image/png"
}
```

I get that data by an MVC controller method which returns a byte[] for the stream and two strings for filename and mime.

I need to make this stream js side a file for the user to download. I saw many approaches involving the Blob object, but still I can't get a correct file. I get a larger file, for example, for a png image but the downloaded version cannot be open as it is not valid.
Here is my try to achieve the goal:

```
[...]
$.ajax({
  url: myUrlToControllerMethod, 
  type: 'POST', 
  data: { fileid: myFileId},
  success: function (res) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var blob = new Blob(res.data.stream, { type: res.data.mime });
    console.warn(blob)
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.info(url)
    a.href = url;
    a.download = res.data.filename;
    document.body.append(a);
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  },
[...]
```

Where am I wrong?

EDIT: I add the controller method:

```
public JsonResult DlFileAsync(int fileid)
{
  var ute = GetUtente();
  DlModel result = FileUtils.DlFileAsync(fileid);
  result.mime = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(result.nomefile);
  var jsonResult =  Json(new GenericResponse(true, result), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
  return jsonResult;
}
```

where: the last three lines (jsonResult thing) are a workaround to an MVC bug as learnt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692836/maxjsonlength-exception-in-asp-net-mvc-during-javascriptserializer).

GenericResponse is a generic data excange class as follows:

```
public class GenericResponse
{
    public bool result { get; set; }
    public object data { get; set; }
}
```

DlModel is a class for file information exchange as follows:

```
public class DlModel
{
    public byte[] stream { get; set; }
    public string filename{ get; set; }
    public string mime { get; set; }
}
```

And FileUtils.DlFileAsync is as follows:

```
public static DlModel DlFileAsync(int fileid)
  var dbFileEntry = getFromDb(fileid);
  var ret = new DlModel() {
    filename = dbFileEntry.FileName,
    stream = dbFileEntry.VarBinaryStream
  };
  return ret;
}
```

Here dbFileEntry is the db record, which has nvarchar(30) type for FileName and varbinary(MAX) for VarBinaryStream.
The corresponding entity class in MVC is as follows:

```
public partial class FileStream : EntityGeneric   
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string FileName { get; set; }
  public byte[] VarBinaryStream { get; set; }
}
```

I think that's almost all.

Comment: It looks like `data.stream` should be `data.data.stream` based on your object, and the usage of references to other properties. Isn't this also already an array? You don't need to pass it as `Blob([data.data.stream], { type: data.data.mime})`, but as `Blob(data.data.stream, { type: data.data.mime})`.

Comment: It is a typo, every data.data is copy-paste error, I will edit and fix that later. I also tried without wrapping again data.stream in an array, but there is minimal change in the resulting file: with the array I get the sequence:
137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0, [...]
while without I get 
13780787113102610000137372688200 [...]
the same without commas. This is obviously not a png, I am doing some conversion terribly wrongly!

Comment: Post the controller method that returns the data please.

Comment: I add that in the db the file is correctly stored, and if recovered in different ways it is valid.